# jBPM 5: how to remove or change a completed task?

Tags: java, workflow, jbpm

let's see if you can give me a hand. Thanks in advance.

I am developing a web application that manage invoices through a workflow with different states. I am using jBPM 5 for that purpose and the way I launch one specific invoice through workflow is next:

- getTaskService().activate(taskId, userId);
- getTaskService().claim(taskId, userId);
- getTaskService().start(taskId, userId);
- getTaskService().complete(taskId, userId, taskContentData);

My problem is the fourth instruction and regards with transactionality. I have a utility class that performs operations once the invoice is processing through its workflow, and if this class throws and exception, the jBPM invoice task remains as 'Completed' when it shouldn't.

My question is: how do I proceed in this situation? I want that 4 previous instructions go in only one transaction, or at least that task status doesn't change to 'Completed' if one exception arises, but this is controlled by jBPM and it doesn't seem easy. Should I try to change task status from 'Completed' to 'Created' again? Or make a new task with status 'Created'?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is old thread but for others,..

in this case it should be handled and dictated via process flow.  You can reference exception handling https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0/userguide/jBPMExceptionManagement.html

Basically if error occurs after invoice is processed (whichever task that is) and if error occurs it should do a error handling condition statement and go back to the previous process(task).